# Ошибка в Visual Studio 2019. Пожалуйста, дождитесь окончания команды редактора

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015

Уже третий раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Очевидно ошибка не в Visual Studio.
Visual Studio 2015 прекрасно работала в течении 8 месяцев потом появилась данная ошибка. Верси 2017 и 2019 нормально работали не более двох недель. Скачивал с официального сайта.

Ошибка появляется сразу когда начинаю писать код или когда нажимаю Tab.
Нужно перезапускать вижуал, но толку с этого особо нет потому что дольше нескольких минут поработать не удается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сбросить все настройки:
Сервис -> импорт и экспорт параметров -> сбросить все параметры
Может поможет, меня часто спасало

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй Git убрать. В настройках.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]